# How can i compare an array with POST data in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, post, compare, associative

Ok, so I am coding a form using only HTML and PHP so, what I have already done is to add data to an array, I'm using post method to send the info, and I can delete data from the array too and print the array content into a table, but i can´t find the way to compare the info that i'm writing in an input with the array content and print the result into a table.

This is my PHP code at the beginning of the file:

```
<?PHP

session_start();

$marca = $_POST['marca'];
$mod = $_POST['modelo'];
$color = $_POST['color'];

if(empty($_SESSION['auto'][$marca])){
    $_SESSION['auto'][$marca] = array(
        'marca' => $marca,
        'modelo' => $mod,
        'color' => $color                   
    );
}   

  if(!is_null(@$_GET['borrar'])){
     unset($_SESSION['auto'][$_GET['borrar']]);
      header('Location:formTransportes.php');
}?>
```

and after that is the HTML content, where Im printing the array is in here:

```
<form action="formTransportes.php" method="post">
        <label>Buscar </label><br>
        <input type="text" name="buscar"><br>  //INPUT OF WHAT IM LOOKING FOR 
        <input type="submit" value="Buscar">
    </form><br> 
    <div id="datos">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>Marca</tr>                  
                <tr>Modelo</tr>                 
                <tr>Color</tr>
                <tr>Acciones</tr>                   
            </thead>    
            <tbody>

                    <?PHP
                    if(!empty($_POST['buscar'])){
                    $clave=$_POST['buscar'];
                    //echo $clave;     ////HERE IS WHERE IT SHOULD BE THE INFO THAT IM LOOKING FOR
                        foreach($_SESSION['auto'] as $i=>$x){


                        }
                    }
                    else{   ///PRINT ALL ARRAY CONTENT

                        foreach($_SESSION['auto'] as $i=>$x){
                            echo"<tr>
                            <td>".$x['marca']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$x['modelo']."</td>".
                            "<td>".$x['color']."</td>".
                            "<td><a href='?borrar=".$i."'>Eliminar</a></td>
                            </tr>";
                        }           

                    }
                    ?>


            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: you have already done that, just use the user input and use it as index on the session array if it exists. what does buscar mean anyway?

Comment: @Ghost http://www.spanishcentral.com/translate/buscar ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- oh right, thats the context of this question anyway, `search` lol :D i think i need a coffee

Comment: @Ghost Enjoy. I on the other hand, would be warm milk if anything. No coffee at this time of night ;-) not here anyway haha!

Comment: @Fred-ii- its morning here so i need one, keep my wits up. anyways, if you want to search each element inside every batch of that saved array you could also use `array_search`, if not, just use `isset` for the index.

Comment: @Ghost Yes, it's a requirement in what we do ;-) am wondering also if OP started the session in the second body of code. *An insight*.

Comment: "buscar" means "search" in spanish, thats why i named the input like that, i know that i have to use the input like that but i just simply can't figure it out

Comment: @Fred-ii- yeah good point, should be in the first line on the search page, @lancbans, either use `array_search` of you just need one result inside the array, if you need multiple, you could use `array_keys` with the second parameter as your search input. and yes you could use that inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys i found a way with "strcmp" function, the search part that i was looking to do is this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['buscar'])){

                        foreach($_SESSION['auto'] as $i=>$x){

                            if(strcmp($_POST['buscar'],$x ['marca'])==0||strcmp($_POST['buscar'],$x ['modelo'])==0||strcmp($_POST['buscar'],$x['color'])==0){
                                echo"<tr>
                                    <td>".$x['marca']."</td>".
                                    "<td>".$x['modelo']."</td>".
                                    "<td>".$x['color']."</td>".
                                    "<td><a href='?borrar=".$i."'>Eliminar</a></td>
                                    <a href='?borrar=".$i."'>Editar</a></td>
                                </tr>";
                            }   
                        }
                    }
```